# Java: write XML according to user defined XSD

Tags: java, xml, parsing, csv, xsd

I'm writing a tool to transform CSV formatted data into XML. The user will specify the parsing method and that is: the XSD for the output, which field in the CSV goes in which field of the resulting XML.

(very simplified use-case) Example:

CSV

```
Ciccio;Pippo;Pappo
1;2;3
```

XSD

```
(more stuff...)
<xs:element name="onetwo">
<xs:element name="three">
<xs:element name="four">
```

USER GIVES RULES

```
   Ciccio -> onetwo
   Pippo -> three
   Pappo -> four
```

I've implemented this in C# using Dataset, how could I do it in Java? I know there's DOM, JAXB etc. but it seems XSD is only used to validate an otherwise created XML. Am I wrong?

Edit:
Everything needs to be at runtime. I don't know what kind of XSD I'll receive so I cannot instantiate objects that don't exist nor populate them with data. So I'm guessing the xjc is not an option.

Comment: XSD can be used to create JAXB classes using a tool that comes with the JDK which can then be used to write out XML... See examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/examples.html

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [SO-1674902](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674902/converting-csv-to-xml-with-an-xsd?rq=1). I must admit that my implementation in C# considered only 1 or 2 XSDs, now I wanted to make it big but apparently there's no solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the `XSD` for your output `XML` file, the best way to create this `XML` would be by using Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB). You might want to refer to: ["Using JAXB"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing.html) tutorial to give you an overview of how to go about using this for your requirement.

The basic idea is as follows:

- Generate JAXB Java classes from an XML schema, i.e. the `XSD` that you have
- Use schema-derived JAXB classes to unmarshal and marshal XML content in a Java application
- Create a Java content tree from scratch using schema-derived JAXB classes
- Unmarshal the data to your output `XML` file.

[Here's another tutorial](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2010/08/29/using-jaxb-to-generate-xml-from-the-java-xsd/) that you might find informative.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but all I see is how to use this tool called xjc to generate Java classes. I need to do everything at runtime, possibly without any JDK installed on the user's machine. The main idea is that I don't know what kind of XSD I'll receive, so I cannot give any binding programmatically. Or, again, am I wrong?

Comment: @Sphaso - no, you are not wrong, jaxb does not make sense for what you are trying to do. jaxb is useful for _statically_ defined xsds.

Answer (score 0):

This is still work in progress, but you could recurse over the XSD writing out elements as you find them to a new document tree.

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(
            "schema.xsd")));

    Document outputDoc = builder.newDocument();

    recurse(document.getDocumentElement(), outputDoc, outputDoc);

    TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(outputDoc),
            new StreamResult(buffer));
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}

public void recurse(Node node, Node outputNode, Document outputDoc) {

    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        if ("xs:element".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
            Element newElement = outputDoc.createElement(element
                    .getAttribute("name"));
            outputNode = outputNode.appendChild(newElement);

           // map elements from CSV values here?
        }
        if ("xs:attribute".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
           //TODO required attributes
        }
    }
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        recurse(list.item(i), outputNode, outputDoc);
    }

}
```

Comment: I had thought about doing something like this, but I see a few issues:- what if we have the same node name in different branches? for example (Xpath notation) /root/branchOne/sameName -- /root/branchTwo/sameName? -How do you pass the xs:element or xs:attribute? do you foreach on each output specified from the user? Yet, I might need to ponder more on your code. In the meanwhile, thank you!