# Generating new XML Structure using XML schema/XSLT and Excel/CSV cell values(with C#)

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xslt, xsd

Detail Description: Actually what i want to achieve is, I have one big Trace file(.xml) from a Profiler. I want to extract some specific Elements from this trace file(.xml) to another structure defined by myself. Now the bottleneck is, i have those elements defined in another csv/xlsx file. Now XML schema/XSLT should work with these values from csv/xlsx.

Transforming no problem. Extracting from excel2007 .xlsx file no problem. 
Only problem is, how to put all this together.

It would be appriciated if some one can answer this post as fast as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting csv to xml with an xsd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674902/converting-csv-to-xml-with-an-xsd)

Comment: "*Now the bottleneck is, i have those elements defined in another csv/xlsx file.*" Is there a good reason for this complication? The best place to define the elements you want, along with what to do with them, is in the XSLT stylesheet itself, using the XSLT language. - P.S. Please indicate if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - can make a huge difference here.