# Generate XML file from CSV using XSD

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xsd

I am trying to implement a C# Windows Forms application to generate XML file from a CSV based on XML's schema. I want to do this as much generic as possible since I am going to transform more than 1000 csv/schemas. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some sort of schema for the CSVs too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty good article exposing appropriate approach for this case

[converting csv to xml with an xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674902/converting-csv-to-xml-with-an-xsd)