# Convert CSV to XML using XSD

Tags: java, xml, csv, xsd

We need to write a program that create an XML file based on CSV file. I prefer to do it in java but I am not a professional programmer.

This is the structure of my desired XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UteXmlComuniction xmlns="http://www....../data">
    <Client Genaral Data>
        <Client>
            <pfPg></pfPg>  
            <name>Arnold</name>
            <Family>Bordon</family>
        </Client>
        <Contract>
            <ContractDetail>
                <Contract>100020</Contract>
                <ContractYear>2019</ContractYear>
            </ContractDetail>
         </Contract>
    </Client Genaral Data>
```

I was expecting the headres in the CSV file would be something like this:

```
"UteXmlComuniction/ClientGeneralData/Client/pfpg", "UteXmlComuniction/ClientGeneralData/Client/name" , 
"UteXmlComuniction/ClientGeneralData/Client/Family" , ...
```

But this is my CSV file

```
"DefinitionPF/PG","ZC_NAME","ZC_FAMI","ZDS_CONT", "ZDC_CONTYEAR"
"PF","Arnold","bordon", "100020", 2018
```

As you can see the name of fields in CSV and in XML are not the same (but the order of fields are always the same) because of this I need to create the field name based on my XSD file

Here is the XSD file that we have

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ww......./data" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UteXmlComunication">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ClientGeneralData" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Client">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="pfpg"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fammily"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Contract">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ContractDetail">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Contract"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ContractYear"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
```

Based on XSD, for example, `"ZC_NAME"` should be named as `"name"`

But as mentioned in this topic ([converting csv to xml with an xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674902/converting-csv-to-xml-with-an-xsd)) the XSD in not a producable language, so my question is how can I do it automatically?

Can you suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: you could try XSLT and Java https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-transform-xml-into-csv-using-xslt.html

Comment: this is XML to csv . My request is csv to xml

Comment: What is the problem? Use a CSV parser and emit XML.